# Set default camera to the rear one in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, dell-latitude, camera

We have a Dell Latitude 5285 laptop/tablet running Windows 10 which, upon opening the Camera app, always starts the *front* 'selfie' camera. There is a button to switch to the rear camera, but after closing and reopening the Camera app, the front camera is started again. In the settings we can change the resolution and other behaviour of the app, but not which one is the default. Is this possible at all?

Comment: Accord to [Default camera is the front one instead of main (rear) - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-camera/default-camera-is-the-front-one-instead-of-main/817ab45e-f0cc-48e9-9e92-5e540688ba10) - no. It is a bug in newer windows.camera app 2017.125.40.0 or 2017.214.20.0 (Windows 10 1703). It used to work in the older version 2016.404.190.0

Comment: Thanks. I had actually read that thread, but was hoping somebody would know a workaround or something ...